# How to construct a surface with a closed curve?

Tags: 3d, surfaces, curves

in 3-dimension, suppose that there is a smooth closed curve $C$.

Can I say that there is a smooth simply connected(no holes) surface whose boundary is $C$?

and is it unique?(I guess not)

like making a bubble I guess it should exist, but hard to prove using mathematical words.

Comment: You can't attach a disk that way to any nontrivial knot.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. can you explain more?

Comment: @rekt: mercio means, let $C$ be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trefoil_knot.